# How do I add up Double Values from multiple String Arrays at the same position? C#

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

I get Strings like this from my database:

> NaN#Nan#44.20216139610997#45.35340149990988#45.44329482112824#45.1593428796393#NaN#NaN

```
values = SQLvalues.Split('#'); //produces Array you can see in the picture
```

> > [image: String Array](String[] values)
> >
> > > Going on further with strings until it ends with about 10 "NaN" Strings again.

What I am doing now is that I sum up all the values from that one Array.

But there will be about 100 more Arrays after this one and I need to add up for example values[8] from this Array with the one at the same position from the next Array.

[image: adding up] hope this visualizes better what I need to do

As I am still an apprentice I don´t have much knowledge on all of this.

I´ve been trying to come with a solution for several hours now but I won´t seem to get anything to work here.

Any help would be great!

My Code:

```
String[] values;
String returnString = "";
List<Double> valueList = new List<Double>();

DateTime time = (DateTime)skzAdapterText.MinTambourChangedTime();

DataTable profilData = skzAdapterText.LoadValuesText(time);

int rowCount = profilData.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    String SQLvalues = (String)profilData.Rows[i][2];

    values = SQLvalues.Split('#');

    double summe = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    foreach (String tmpRow in values)
    {
        Double value;
        if (double.TryParse(tmpRow, NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value)
        && !double.IsNaN(value))
        {
            counter++;
            summe = summe + value;
        }
    }

    if (summe != 0 && counter != 0)
        valueList.Add(summe / counter);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your posted code? Please be precise. Have you put down breakpoints and walked through as its running, inspecting variables' values?

Comment: Why can't you fix this by using SUM statements in the source query? Are the values actually stored as packed/delimited values like that in the database?

Comment: The Code works, but as for now it adds up all values from that one Array. As I said in my question I need it to sum up the value at lets say position 8 with the value from position 8 from the next 100 arrays. Which is where I don´t know how to do it.

Comment: @keithwill-the-upvoter I am not used to what I can do and where I can do stuff with sql, still very new but I´ll try to use your idea and see what is possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to sum up the values at the same positions of the arrays, I assume that all these array have the same length. Then first declare the required arrays. You also must probably calculate the average for each array position, so you also need an array for the counter and the averages.

```cs
double[] average = null;
int rowCount = profilData.Rows.Count;

if (rowCount > 0) {
    string[] values = ((string)profilData.Rows[0][2]).Split('#');
    int n = values.Length;
    double[] sum = new double[n];
    double[] counter = new double[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        values = ((string)profilData.Rows[i][2]).Split('#');
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (double.TryParse(values[j], NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double value) && !double.IsNaN(value)) {
                counter[j]++;
                sum[j] += value;
            }
        }
    }
    average = new double[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (counter[i] != 0) {
            average[i] = sum[i] / counter[i];
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot calculate the average while summing up, since you must divide the total sum by the total count. Therefore, I added another loop calculating the averages at each array position after the summing phase.

Comment: I just had to paste this in and adjust some parts of my own code and it works just the way It should. Thank you for the awnser! - appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

The basic sum can be reduced like so:

```
values = SQLvalues.Split('#'); 
double sum = values.Where(v => v != "NaN").Select(v => double.Parse(v)).Sum();
```

For a specific position, say index 8, within many rows:

```
//Read the data from DB
DataTable profilData = skzAdapterText.LoadValuesText(time);

//parse out the values
var rowValueArrays = // will be a List<double[]>
    profilData.Rows.
    Select(r => r[2].Split('#').Select(v => v == "NaN"?0.0:double.Parse(v)).ToArray()).
    ToList();

// sum the entries at index 8
double sumAt8 = rowValueArrays.Select(r => r[8]).Sum();
```

You say you are an apprentice, and so the syntax here may be unfamiliar to you and seem difficult to understand. But I want to emphasize the power here. The combination of IEnumerable, lambda expressions, and linq operations reduced the original sample down to two lines of code, and solved the full problem in what is technically three lines (spread out a little for readability). If I wanted to sacrifice any sense of style or maintainability, *we could do it in just one line of code*.

In short, it is well worth your time to learn how to write code this way. With practice, reading and writing code this way can become easy and greatly increase your speed and capability as a programmer.

I also see attempts to compute an average. Continuing from the end of the previous code:

```
int countAt8 = rowValuesArrays.Count(r => r[8] != 0.0);
double average = sumAt8 / countAt8;
```

Finally, I need to point out delimited data like this in a column is an abuse of the database and very poor practice. Schemas like this are considered **broken**, and need to be *fixed*.

Comment: Thanks for this awnser. When I try using the Code it says "DataRowCollection does not contain a definition for Select", I´m alreay using the namespace System.Linq so I don´t get why it returns me this error.
Also given your Code, do I need to replace everything of mine for it to work? Also I am educating myself on lambda and linq operations right now. - seems very helpful to me already.

So if the data is delimited rn, what would be a better approach to store the data?
I´d also be happy with a reference to any source I can educate myself on.